# How to archive files with multiple conditions?

Tags: archive, find, bzip2

How do I find all files in a folder(including subfolders) with extension jpg or bmp, with size between 6 and 46 kilobytes, last modified between 11 and 19 June 2011 or between 24 July and 2 August inclusively and add all these files to an archive(bzip2)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try a similar command (but it actually has a *flaw*):

`$ find . \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.bmp" \) -and \( -size +6k -and -size -46k \) -and \( \( -newermt "2011-06-11" -and ! -newermt "2011-06-19" \) -or \( -newermt "2011-07-24" -and ! -newermt "2011-08-02" \) \) -print0 | xargs -0 tar cjf out.tar.bz2 --files-from=-`

Not sure about the dates, though. It works for me as `YYYY-MM-DD` but it might change with the language settings.

**Update:**

There is a major conceptual mistake in the previous example.

Basically the `xargs` command works in „passes” (eg. takes as much filenames as possible to cram into a command line and calls the `tar` command). So `out.tar.bz2` **gets rewritten at every pass**.

It may not be noticed with a few dozen test files, but a few hundred will trigger the bug for sure. So the command needs to be rewritten as follows:

`$ find . \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.bmp" \) -and \( -size +6k -and -size -46k \) -and \( \( -newermt "2011-06-11" -and ! -newermt "2011-06-20" \) -or \( -newermt "2011-07-24" -and ! -newermt "2011-08-03" \) \) -print0 | tar cjf out.tar.bz2 --null --files-from=-`

The main difference is the absence of `xargs` and using the `--null` option for `tar`. This option will tell `tar` to read *null terminated* filenames (as produced by the `find` commands `-print0` option). The whole reason behind these null terminated filenames are to avoid filenames containing special characters (eg. whitespace), that would otherwise break the `tar` command.

Another possible bug to point out is the **date range specification**. The upper end of date range should be increased by 1 day (otherwise files modified on that day will be omitted).

Comment: @johnny Found a major flaw in the implementation, fix posted with explanation.